# Reduction stack overflow with static size list

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I have following code implementing static sized vectors implemented as lists which compiles fine:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Normalise #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE IncoherentInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

infixr 5 :.
data Vector :: Nat -> * -> * where
  (:-:):: Vector 0 a
  (:.) :: a -> Vector (n-1) a -> Vector n a

deriving instance Show a => Show (Vector n a)

instance Functor (Vector n) where
  fmap f (:-:) = (:-:)
  fmap f (x :. xs) = f x :. fmap f xs

type x > y = CmpNat x y ~ 'GT

instance Applicative (Vector 0) where
  pure f    = (:-:)
  (<*>) _ _ = (:-:)

instance (Applicative (Vector (n-1)), n > 0 ) => Applicative (Vector n) where
  pure (f::a)          = f :. (pure f :: Vector (n-1) a)
  (f:.fs) <*> (x:.xs) = f x :. (fs <*> xs)
```

However when i try to define elementwise sum for these vectors like this:

```
(<+>) :: Num a => Vector n a -> Vector n a -> Vector n a
v1 <+> v2 = (+) <$> v1 <*> v2
```

I get compilation error

```
Reduction stack overflow; size = 201
When simplifying the following type: Applicative (Vector s0)
(...)
In the expression: (+) <$> v1 <*> v2
```

What is the cause of this error if i can type right hand expression in ghci and it works fine, and how to avoid it in the future?

I am using ghc 8.0.1 with natnormalize 0.5.2

Comment: (1) "i can type right hand expression in ghci and it works fine" -- what does GHCi say if you ask it the type of the right hand expression? (2) A guess: don't you need to put the `(Applicative (Vector (n-1)), n > 0 )` constraints in the signature of `(<+>)` as well?

Comment: I should be more specific next time, because that expression worked with specified values, not as function definition. However your about Applicative constraint suggestion worked. Could you elaborate as to why i need to specify that (Vector n) is instance of Applicative, as all vector lengths should be instantiated as applicatives? The (n > 0) constraint isn't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > A guess: don't you need to put the [constraints] in the signature of `(<+>)` as well?
>
> [Your] `Applicative` constraint suggestion worked. Could you elaborate as to why i need to specify that `(Vector n)` is instance of Applicative, as all vector lengths should be instantiated as applicatives?

In a nutshell, GHC has no means of reaching that conclusion inductively. Rather, what the type checker does on being told you need `Applicative (Vector n)` is stepping back and looking at `Applicative (Vector (n - 1))`, in order to see whether `(Applicative (Vector (n - 1)), n > 0) => Applicative n` is satisfied. Since you aren't working with a concrete `n`, that never terminates (that is the difference from your test with specific values). That being so, you need to provide extra information. By the way, you will get the same "Reduction stack overflow" error if you try something more prosaic, such as:

```
GHCi> :t undefined == (undefined :: [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[a]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]])
```

Since `Eq [a]` requires `Eq a`, if `a ~ [b]` then `Eq b` also has to be checked, and so forth.

On another note, as far as I'm aware of it is more usual to write this sort of constraint in terms of `KnownNat` rather than e.g. `Applicative`, in order to minimise the amount of constraints you have to propagate in the signatures of your functions. Cf. for instance [the source of `CLaSH.Sized.Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clash-prelude-0.11/docs/src/CLaSH-Sized-Vector.html) (someone more well versed in this sort of type-level programming than me might be able to give more specific advice).